# Tengo un problema con java.lang.StackOverflowError al tratar de imprimir el frente de un nodo de una lista circular doblemente enlazada

Tags: java

Bueno para empezar tengo una ***Clase Lista*** con el siguiente método:

```
public void mostrarLista() {

    if (isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("**LISTA VACIA** ");
    } else {
        System.out.println(front);
    }

}
```

y al llamar el método del main me manda esta muestra de la excepción.

```
 case 3:
   L1.mostrarLista();
 break;
```

(L1 es el objeto de la ***Clase Lista***)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:136)
at cLista.Automovil.toString(Automovil.java:39)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
at cLista.Nodo.toString(Nodo.java:50)
```

Y estas son las lineas de código que me marcan error según las excepciones.

Este es de la ***Clase Automóvil***

```
  @Override
public String toString() {
    return "\n =========||VEHICULO ||========= \n\t  "
            + "Placas: " + placas + "\n\t  Modelo: "
            + modelo + "\n\t  Color:  "
            + color;
}
```

Y este la del nodo.

```
   @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Nodo{" + "dato= " + getDato() + ", Siguente= " + getNext() + '}';
    }
```

No entiendo cual es el error al querer imprimir un dato de tipo nodo (front).
alguien sabe donde radica exactamente mi problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Nodo{" + "dato= " + getDato() + ", Siguente= " + getNext() + '}';
 }
```

*getNext()* devuelve el siguiente nodo. Al concatenar al String, el compilador automáticamente a se método *toString()*. Y ese método a su vez hace *getNext()* para obtener el tercer modo de la lista.

Y como es una lista circular, siempre *getNext* te devolverá un modo del que se hará *toString*, hasta que no haya sitio en el stack.

Comment: Ya veo más claro el problema, como bien mencionas como es una lista circular, al momento de imprimir el nodo _front_ a su vez  imprime el nodo siguiente  con el `getNext()` entra en un bucle  ya que el último nodo _last_ te lleva a _front_ y se repite otra vez hasta que el stack de llene. Tú explicación fue muy clara.